# Is it against the law to attempt gaining other person's banking information?

Tags: banking

This is a purely theoretical question. For example burglary is a crime. An attempted burglary is also a crime, but not as severe as a real one.

Getting other person's banking information (the number of accounts, the total amount) is a crime. But is an attempt also considered a crime ?

For example, if I work as a realtor. Can I call to my client's banker, and ask  questions about my client's banking info (total savings, liquid assets)  ? Is this legally okay ? Or do I violate any law by attempting to get this info ? The banker will most likely not share this info, but is my attempt considered illegal ? If yes, then what article of what law am I violating ?

Comment: Doy you have a specific reference for "getting someone's banking info is a crime"? It'd help in finding the specific statute. Also, in what jurisdiction?

Comment: As far as US federal law is concerned, I'm just seeing penalties for *disclosure* or *use* of private financial info, not for obtaining it. Also, I'd question the point of calling asking for info if it *is* illegal to obtain that info.

Comment: @cpast I suspect that banking regulations may impose an obligation on financial institutions to protect the privacy of their customers' information; if this is the case then it may not be unlawful to gain another person's information, but it could be a regulatory breach for the institution to allow it,.

Answer (score 1):

> Getting other person's banking information (the number of accounts, the total amount) is a crime.

Really? In which jurisdiction and in which law in that jurisdiction is this a crime?

Methods that might be used such as stealing mail or hacking computer systems are certainly a crime but e.g. asking someone how much money they have and how many bank accounts, while extremely rude, is not criminal.

Ask away; I would expect the banker to politely (or otherwise) to fornicate off unless they had been given an instruction from their client to tell you.

Many countries, Australia being one, have credit reporting agencies that will sell you a credit worthiness report on individuals and corporations. They do not go into that level of detail and you must supply a privacy release form from the subject.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not a crime to request the information. But it can be a crime to disclose the information: Information privacy law.

Comment: Are you able to provide a more specific reference, by chance?